# SSRS - Deploying a Reporting Services Report to Multiple Servers at Once

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, deployment, ssrs-2012

I have a Visual Studio Project with some reports I created. Each report has its own DataSource, with a defined user and password and a embedded connection, and I use this expression for the string connection that works perfectly:

```
="Data Source="+Parameters!server.Value+ ";Initial Catalog="+Parameters!database.Value
```

When I want to deploy a single report to a specified server , I have to change the **TargetServerURL** everytime, in the property pages of the project:

[image]

This works perfectly when I deploy a report in the server I want. The problem comes when I want to deploy the same report in many servers, for different reasons (a new report is created, changes in a report, etc) because I have to do the same process many times (change TargetServerURL, then to deploy). Is there a way to deploy one single report in multiple servers at the same time?

I already checked this link:

[How to deploy many reports to many SSRS Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778867/how-to-deploy-many-reports-to-many-ssrs-servers)

I tried the point with the manually script, but the problem is that the whole project is deployed and *DataSource* properties in each report lost his value, so doesn't work for me.

**EDIT**

The script I've tried is in this link:

https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/reporting-services/ssrs-migration-rss/ssrs_migration.rss

But as can seen in the *LIMITATIONS* part, the data sources with stored credentials must be re-entered. Also this deploy the entire project, and not an specified report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern tool for this sort of task is Azure DevOps.  There is a leading extension in the marketplace for this which should get you started.  It is quite well supported by the developer and a few other contributors, and is all open-source.  The heart of it is a PowerShell script that integrates DevOps and SSRS deployment:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mmajcica.deploy-ssrs

Here's the github repo with source code, more doco and an active issues register:

https://github.com/mmajcica/DeploySsrs

Answer (score 3):

You can use a configuration manager on top right to set up various environments. It just won't be one click in all servers. You will still need to go and choose the environments you wish to deploy to.

Comment: I've tried but is not the solution I'm looking for...